# Bitnami Solr 5 schema file

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore8

I am trying to configure sitecore with Solr 5, but an issue occur when restarting the SOLR services the schema.xml will be renamed to schema.xml.bak which prevent sitecore from connecting to SOLR.

Also a file "managed-schema" is created once restarting services?! Any Ideas.

Comment: did you check if stopping Sitecore instance and restarting Solr keep the original schema.xml without rename it?

Comment: Yes it keep it sometimes but I am now sure why the reaming happened sometimes?

Comment: That's a strange behavior, and how about reinstall Solr and see if the same happens? Do you know if any script runs while SOLR services are restarted?